# Issues updating database from a detailed DataTable in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, next.js

I am using a DataTable component in my Next.js application to display and edit a list of speakers. Each row represents a speaker, and each column an attribute, much like a datasheet. After making changes to the values in this table, I want to send the updated speaker data back to my database.

Here's a summarized structure of my setup:

***Parent Component:***

```
// ... imports ...
type AllSpeakerTypes = Speaker & 
// ... (all the other types) ...

type Props = AllSpeakerTypes;

const Products: React.FC<{ speakers: Props[] }> = ({ speakers }) => {
  // ... logic ...

  return (
    <DataTable
      items={speakers}
      handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
    />
  );
};

const handleSubmit = async (updatedSpeaker: Props) => {
  console.log("handleSubmit has been triggered with: ", updatedSpeaker);
  try {
    const response = await axios.put(
      `${backendURL}/speakers/${updatedSpeaker.id}`,
      updatedSpeaker
    );
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Speaker updated successfully");
    } else {
      console.log("Error updating Speaker");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Something went wrong: ", error);
  }
};

// ... more code ...
```

---

***DataTable (Child) Component:***

```
interface ItemProps
  extends Optional<Speaker>,
// ... (all the other Optional types) ...

interface DataTableProps {
  items: ItemProps[];
  handleUpdate?: (
    itemIdx: number,
    fieldKey: string,
    newValue: string
  ) => Promise<void>;
  handleSubmit?: (updatedSpeaker: ItemProps) => Promise<void>;
}

const DataTable: React.FC<DataTableProps> = ({
  items,
  handleUpdate,
  handleSubmit,
}) => {
  // ... logic ...
  const handleEditSaveClick = () => {
    // ... logic ...
    items.forEach((item, idx) => {
      let hasChanges = false;
      const updatedItem: any = {};
      // ... logic ...
      if (hasChanges) {
        handleSubmit({ ...initialItems[idx], ...updatedItem });
      }
    });
  };
};

export default DataTable;
```

Now, when I click a button in the DataTable component to trigger the handleSubmit function, the database is not getting updated. The console logs in the handleSubmit function do trigger, so it's not an issue of the function not being called.

The main problem seems to be with the data not being sent to the database or not being processed correctly on the backend. Any idea why this might be happening? How can I ensure that my updated speaker data is correctly sent and processed by my backend?

Comment: Does the console log of "Speaker updated successfully" or "Error updating Speaker" at least show up? You could also log out `response` and see what response you have gotten.

Comment: @taiwei-tuan doesn’t throw any error or message.